# While playing audio app crashed. But works fine in simulator

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I have developed a Xamarin iOS app. It's working fine in the simulator but it crashed on iPad.Herewith I have attached the crash report for the reference.

```
Crash Report
{
"id" : "AA84rm_MxL6uGDIA5fFvMoc",
"timestamp" : "2020-03-10T14:29:41.934Z[UTC]",
"appAdamId" : 1454312979,
"cfBundleShortVersion" : "1.1",
"cfBundleVersion" : "7.0",
"deviceModel" : "iPad7,11",
"osVersion" : "13.1.1",
"locale" : "en-US",
"carrier" : null,
"timezone" : "America/New_York",
"architecture" : "arm64",
"connectionStatus" : "WI_FI",
"pairedAppleWatch" : "",
"appUptimeMillis" : null,
"availableDiskBytes" : 20617326592,
"totalDiskBytes" : 31989469184,
"networkType" : null,
"batteryPercentage" : 65,
"screenWidth" : 810,
"screenHeight" : 1080,
"emailAddress" : "abc@abc.com",
"comment" : null
}
```

Comment: If that is a crash report, where is the list of threads with their symbolicated call stacks? (Rhetorical speaking). Sorry, but what you got there is a JSON with some unrelated informations, but not a crash report. You will find the crashlog in xcodes organizer or on your device if not imported yet.

Comment: Add ''Privacy - Media library usage description'' attribute in info.plist

Comment: Please check them in real time as you launch the app to device,enable the Device console logs Visual Studio (Windows):
1. Use the View->Other Windows->Device Log menu to launch the Device Log pane.
2. Choose the device in the Choose Device drop down list at the top of the pane.  Xamarin/Visual Studio (Mac):
1. Use the View->Pads->Device Log menu to launch the Device Log pane.
2. Choose the device in the Choose Device drop down list at the top of the pane.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I find out the issue with a memory leak. The app was crashing as soon as it gets around 700MB of memory. After fixing, memory is pretty much staying under 180MB. Now its playing well.